# apache rewrite rule doesn't redirect all urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have .htaccess site with many domain names for the same site

I want user when comes to specific domain to be redirected to another domain , I have this code in htaccess file , it redirects well but not for all urls , I want all requests to be redirected to the new domain with the same urls.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: It redirect well but not for all urls.. do you mean www\.olddomain\.com is being redirected to www\.newdomain\.com but not www\.olddomain\.com/foo ?

Comment: yes , exactly , very strange

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my .htaccess file is used with many domains too , and I have each domain rules in a block separated by a comment , and each domain has some redirection to folder in case specific URL specified in URL like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule   ^example/(.*)$   folder1/$1  [QSA,L] RewriteRule  
RewriteRule   ^fold2/(.*)$   folder2/$1  [QSA,L]
```

so I have to add my code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

before any redirects to make it run probably and redirects all URL.